# Expresso Store : Checkout form based on payment method

Tags: expresso-store

I'm working on an implementation and I'm using the most current version of the Expresso Store plugin. So far everything is working great, only I'm having trouble getting the payment method form to show up based on the payment method selected.

Currently I'm using `{payment_method_options}` inside of a `{exp:store:checkout}` block. I have a select that correctly displays the payment options but I'm unsure how to tie that together with a credit card form (I've used the [Credit Card Details](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#credit_card_details) section of the docs to build a checkout form),or say another payment method like PayPal.

Does anyone have a direction to point me in, or have an example implementation that I could examine?

EE v2.5.3
Store v1.6.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on whether you're taking payment on-site or off-site (handing over to the payment gateway's servers to take the payment and then sending the users back to your site). If you're taking payments on your site then you really need to be [PCI-DSS compliant](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/) which is no small feat. Personally I'd always look hand over to the payment gateway to keep things simple.

If you are sending over to the payment gateway then you wont need the card details form on your site. All you'd need to do is to set the [payment_method](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#payment_method) as the parameter on your store checkout tag along with a [return](https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/checkout_tag.html#return) URL.

You'd need to make sure that you've setup your chosen gateway in Store > Settings > Payment methods, first. Create the new gateway, ensure that it's enabled and then enter in your account credentials.

If you're allowing the user to select their payment method then that can be provided with a simple dropdown:

```
{field:payment_method}
```

Note, that you'll need to setup the payment methods in Store Settings first to see them appear in this dropdown.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking would need to happen in the end. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: No problem. I find that when in the early stage of testing it can be useful to use the form with a 'dummy' gateway so you can just enter random information locally for quick order processing. Then as things advance turn on your real gateway and start testing remotely.